Warehouse heating
I am a student currently working on an energy management project focused on an industrial warehouse.
I am trying to understand how the warehouse heating is managed and controlled. From what I understand so far, a boiler (separate from the one used for steam production) is used to heat a glycol solution to approximately 95°C. The hot glycol flows through pipes and splits off to unit heaters, where fans move air across the glycol coils to heat the surrounding air in the warehouse. Additionally, the glycol heats air in air handling units, which recirculate the air, and it also heats air from the makeup air unit.
Is the heating of the recirculated air in Door 2 occurring to maintain a uniform temperature in the warehouse on the far right? Additionally, is air exhausted outside warehouse from the air handling unit on the left (Door 3) if so, why is glycol used to heat it?
The fan operation follows specific control logic:
If the fan switch is set to "AUTO", it operates only when the warehouse temperature is below the set point (7°C).
If the fan switch is set to "ON", the fan will run continuously, regardless of temperature.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to evaluate the current space heating system. I plan to use the values in the attached diagram as a baseline and compare them to the actual data from the facility.

Define "evaluate"? running costs? Time to reach desired temperature? Noise level? Boiler emissions? Then design of building? does it have insulation? Big doors that are always open? Lots of leaky windows? Have you done, or even considered, a thermal analysis of the building with an infra red camera?

I don’t have information on the time it takes to reach the desired temperature in the warehouse, but my plan is to compare how the heating system actually operates versus how it was designed to function. Specifically, I want to evaluate the power consumed by the fans and the fuel input to the boiler, as measured by fuel meters.
The facility produces its own electricity on-site, but they pay for the natural gas used in boilers. Unfortunately, I haven’t conducted an on-site audit to track how frequently the doors are opened, though I do know that the warehouse doesn’t have any windows.

To address the door heaters.
None of the heaters are blowing out of the building. The door heaters are mounted above the doors with those $90^o$ nozzles pointing downwards. These provide an adjustable air curtain to prevent the inflow of cold outside air.
Makeup air from the main air handler will generally find its own way out of the building if suitable vents are not provided.
